# Why my dota 2 always update after switch the OS?

Tags: steam, dota-2

I have 2 OS on my laptop, windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I use 1 steam library folder for that both OS. But my questions is why my dota 2 always update after switch the OS? The update size is always same. when I switch from windows to ubuntu update size is about 460MB and when I switch from ubuntu to windows update size is 846.4MB. Why it happens, can I make no update even if I change my OS with the same steam library?

Comment: Are you running them via any emulator or are they native?  The downloads will be OS specific optimization.  Obviously DirectX will not be on Linux, while OpenGL on Windows have always sucked.

Comment: @nelson running native via grub, I use vulkan instead directX or openGL on both OS, it should permanently have OS specific optimization, right? Why I must download every change the OS?

Comment: I don't think they expected users to play in different OS with the same installation.  The fact that the game can handle it is already a huge kudos to the developers... They didn't just bake the optimization into the whole thing, but made it separate.

Answer (score 3):

Steam and Dota2 have native binaries for Linux. Spare yourself the headache and just run the native version of Dota2.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. GRUB is a bootloader.

Comment: True, this is what happens if you try to write 2 answers at the same time. (i edited it).

Comment: I dont undestand, what do you mean? did you  install dota different library location on both OS? It's imposible because no disk space

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur Yes. dota2 needs 16 gb of space. 2 Installs is just 32gb. You dont have that much space left? I mean you could just boot into windows whenever you want to play dota ... thats not too much of an inconvenience imho.

Comment: Now Dota is about 22GB total 44GB, my drive only 128gb -_-